# The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication error When running ssis from stored proc in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssis-2012

I am getting the following error:

The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows Authentication

I have a ssrs report which uses a dataset derived from a stored procedure.  The stored procedure first creates an execution and executes a ssis package before drawing the data.  In visual studio I can preview the report fine.  The data source uses integrated security (though I wish I could pass a sql server account).  When I upload the report to SSRS it gives me the error about using an account with windows auth.  I checked the datasource on the server and it is set to use windows auth.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix this.

my sql server is 2012 r2 (ssrs is 2008)

Comment: The title of this question talks about SSIS, but the body is talking about SSRS. What are you trying to do here? SSRS data sources work best when using SQL Server authentication. SSRS cannot pass your credentials through to the SQL Server, so Windows authentication will not work..

Comment: I managed to make it work.  SSRS in visual studio didn't let me do this (probably I was doing it wrong) but on the server I could alter the data source to use a windows logon instead of sql auth and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot execute SSIS packages which are stored on your SSISDB Catalog using a SQL Server account.

This is why changing the user which is attempting to start the SSIS package to a 'Windows Authentication user' works.

A similar issue can be found here;

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bbd2b556-8f68-4e04-94d1-754127886361/unable-to-execute-ssis-package-from-sql-server-login?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 1):

```
Integrated Security = SSPI;
```

Ignores UserId and Passwords and uses Windows Authentification :D

Answer (score 1):

schedule the SSIS package as a job with windows authentication, then call the job itself using

USE msdb;

GO

EXEC   dbo.sp_start_job N'NAME OF JOB';
GO

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Apparently putting a windows login in the data source worked, couldn't get it to go in visual studio but updating the datasource on ssrs did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trusted_Connection = False;
Password = ***;
User ID = ***;
Data Source = localhost;
Initial Catalog = master;
Integrated Security = SSPI;
```

This connection string worked for me!